# visual studio 2019 shows no error, but the driver is not compiled

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver

I'm trying to build a HelloWorld driver project. So I installed VS 2019 and WDK for Windows 10. I started from an empty WDM project, added DriverEntry and many other things, but when I build the project, VS shows the following:

```
1>Building 'MyDriver1' with toolset 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0' and the 'Desktop' target platform.
1>Stamping x64\Debug\MyDriver1.inf
1>Stamping [Version] section with DriverVer=11/25/2019,10.3.28.19
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The build has failed, no `.sys` file is generated, no warnings either, what was wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I accidentally removed lines from the INF file. After restoring them, VS can correctly compile .sys files